# jQuery: select first anchor that contains any text

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, selector

Consider the following markup:

```
<a href="#"></a>
<a href="#"><img src="foo.png" /></a>
<a href="#">aaa</a>
<a href="#">bbb</a>
```

Is it possible to use a jQuery selector to get the first anchor that contains any text (but not if it contains only image(s))? (In this case, the `aaa` one)

Comment: What about `<a href="#">foo<b>bar</b></a>` and `<a href="#"><b>bar</b></a>`?

Comment: Both of these cases should be targeted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery doesn't have a lazy `first` selector, so you will still end up matching all of the anchor tags before filtering them:

```
$('a').filter(function() {
    return $(this).text();
}).first()
```

Comment: I guess it will be possible to stop the filter function after it finds the first match by checking a `isFound` boolean first, which will make it more efficient.

Comment: @exizt: `filter()` will be called on every element in the array. You can't really stop it unless you use a loop like `$.each`, but if you're using jQuery in the first place, there's no point in micro-optimizations.

Comment: Ah yes, but it won't call `text()` method of every one if we check for `isFound` first. Though it's indeed doubtful that this kind of optimization would have noticeable performance benefits.

Answer (score 2):

This complex selector first checks that the element does not have any children, then ensures that the element is not empty.

```
var anchor = $("a:not(:has(img)):not(:empty)").eq(0);
```

**Working Example** http://jsfiddle.net/dZLKE/3/

Comment: Yep, this one gets the image.

Comment: What about empty children?

Comment: @Blender wouldn't `:not(:empty)` cover that?

Comment: @Kobi Its all good, you got me to run an extra test. Win-Win scenario

Comment: @KevinBowersox It doesn't, actually (sorry if I haven't made that clear). It should've gotten `foo <b>bar</b>`

Comment: In terms of performance complex selectors like this are not the best solution. I compare it here with my answer:  http://jsperf.com/complex-vs-simple

Comment: @exizt that is a quick fix, just switched `:not(:has(*))` to `:not(:has(img))`

Comment: @KevinBowersox, ah, but now it fails on `<a href="#"><span></span></a>` (by getting it).

Answer (score 0):

```
var txtEl;
$('a').each(function(i, el){
  var text = $(el).text();
  if(text != ""){
     txtEl = el;
     return false;
  }
});
```

[Jquery Selector](http://jquery-this.blogspot.com/jquery.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a').each(function(){
    if($.trim($(this).text()) != ''){
       alert($(this).text());
    }
});
```

Living demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AGKeY/2/

Comment: `String.prototype.trim()` isn't available in IE8 and below. Use `$.trim()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

This will return the first anchor with text from a container, without looping through all the elements.

```
var getFirstAnchorWithText = function (container) {

    var anchor = null;

    container.find('a').each(function () {
        if ($(this).text()) {
            anchor = $(this);
            return false; // Exits from the loop as soon as the element is found
        }
    });

    return anchor;

}
```

Demo Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/kMhH3/4/).